# ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4822: error in SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

I can try to import an mysql 5.1 dump into mysql 5.5 but i received this is the error:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4822: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values, default, is_required, error_message ) VALUES ( 1, 'Nome', 'firstname', 0' at line 1

```
 CREATE TABLE `user_field` (
   `field_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `values` text,
  `default` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `is_required` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `error_message` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`field_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `user_field` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user_field` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `user_field` ( field_id, name, column_name, type, values, default, is_required, error_message ) VALUES ( 1, 'Nome', 'firstname', 0, NULL, '', 0, 'Inserisci il nome' );
INSERT INTO `user_field` ( field_id, name, column_name, type, values, default, is_required, error_message ) VALUES ( 2, 'Cognome', 'lastname', 0, NULL, '', 0, 'Inserisci il cognome' );
```

Comment: values is a keyword in mysql, so a field name should be enclosed with tilt ` sign. do a search replace using a text editor to enclose the field values with tilt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) like `values` and `default` with backticks

```
INSERT INTO `user_field` (field_id, ..., `values`, `default`, ...)
```

Comment: Corrected the reserve words with escape